# how to modify my EventHandler for logging into database, so that and SQLException is treated as an incorrect loggin and the rogram continues?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, event-handling

**problem:**

My question is how to modify my code so that it checks if a login is correct or not?

```
class connect implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    connect(String username, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testDatabase", username, password);
            Database database = new Database(connection);
            database.show();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

**context:**

Hello,

I'm a beginner programmer. I've written a program that logs into a database and let's the user see and modify it through a GUI.

I'd prefer if the connection object would throw an exception which could be caught in a loop and the loop would end only when a successful connection is established. I know that this is a simple problem, but I couldn't find a previous stackoverflow question and it would be great to have a quick answer since I don't have the time right now to start reading a tutorial on this somewhere online.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Connection connection = null;
    do {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testDatabase", username, password);
            Database database = new Database(connection);
            database.show();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (connection == null);
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't differ between any other sqlexception and wrong credentials. While it does work it would be nice to inform the user that there is some other problem, like wrong server name.